# why the error occurs Didn't find class "java.lang.ClassValue"?

Tags: java, android, jython, classnotfoundexception

i use jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar in my application...
compiler is Android Studio 2020 3.1...
minSdk 26 in build.gradle.
An error occurs on the line

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
```

Code:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.*;
public class SimpleEmbedded {
public static void main(String []args) throws PyException {
    [PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();][1]
  ///  System.out.println("Hello, world from Java");
  //  interp.execfile("hello.py");
  ///  interp.set("a", new PyInteger(42));
  //  interp.exec("print a");
  //  interp.exec("x = 2+2");
  //  PyObject x = interp.get("x");
  //  System.out.println("x: "+x);
    System.out.println("Goodbye ");
}
}
```

Error:

```
2021-09-29 21:19:12.368 3202-3202/com.serg.myjython E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.serg.myjython, PID: 3202
    **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/ClassValue**;
        at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:2137)
...
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.ClassValue"** on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~VsbgLG28nD-Vw7dAU-vIyA==/com.serg.myjython-ODUx9HepPkKuKHI_uTVWdw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~VsbgLG28nD-Vw7dAU-vIyA==/com.serg.myjython-ODUx9HepPkKuKHI_uTVWdw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the **android jdk** (built into the phone) does not have the class `java.lang.ClassValue`. You should copy the class from the `open JDK` or `Oracle JDK`, and fix the unable called APIs.